# check if IsNumeric using Me.Controls()

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform with dozens of text boxes where the user should input only numbers from 1 to 6. When the form is completed the user clicks Save and the numbers are added to an Excel table.

As the text boxes are quite a lot I used the following code to read their value:

```
' Text boxes name are: txt_a01, txt_a02, txt_a03...
For i = 1 To 5
    ws.Cells(iRow, i).Value = Me.Controls("txt_a0" & i).Value
Next

' Here text boxes name are: txt_b01, txt_b02, txt_b03...
For i = 6 To 10
    ws.Cells(iRow, i).Value = Me.Controls("txt_b0" & i - 5).Value
Next

etc.
```

rather than write dozens of times:

```
ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.txt_a01.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.txt_a02.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.txt_a03.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.txt_a04.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.txt_a05.Value
```

Now I would like to check - during input - if the user has really added a number and if its between 1 and 6. Normally I would do it like this:

```
Private Sub txt_a01_AfterUpdate()
    If Not IsNumeric(txt_a01.Value) Then
        MsgBox ("Only numbers accepted")
    End If
End Sub
```

But as I use a FOR - LOOP and Me.Controls() to read the text box values I don't understand how to write down the _AfterUpdate Sub.

Comment: What do you want to happen if one of them fails the test? Just ignore that value, or not write any values, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attach dynamically an event handler on form load or you could create a custom control with an event.
Personally I prefer use custom control and KeyPressEventHandler to refuse all not allowed chars.

You may create a class to handle the event :

```
Private WithEvents m_oTextBox as TextBox

Public Property Set TextBox(ByVal oTextBox as TextBox)
Set m_oTextBox = oTextBox
End Property

Private Sub m_oTextBox_Change()
' Do something
End Sub
```

then, for each control:

```
Dim myEventHandler As TextBoxEventHandler
        Set myEventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler

        Set myEventHandler.TextBox = oControl

        m_oCollectionOfEventHandlers.Add myEventHandler
```